# How to generate paper wallet on myetherwallet.com?

Tags: myetherwallet

I need your help!
I would like to generate a paper wallet (cold storage) for my Ether.
I followed instructions in order to do so:

1. went on myetherwallet.com
2. Input password
3. Clicked on Generate wallet
4. This shows:[image]
5. When I click on download : [image]
6. It's just a bunch of numbers and text !! [

Can anyone help? Thanks a lot in advance! :o)

Answer (score 5):

you are on the right way just continue, after downloading the json file press the button 'i understand, continue' then choose print.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

While @Badr Bellaj's answer is correct, here is an alternative way that will also work after you generate your account and restart your browser.

Download that `UTC-...` file which is your private key encrypted with your password (you've already done this). Then go back to MEW and select View Wallet Info > Keystore file (UTC/JSON) > enter your password. That page will show you all the information which you can print out any time you want.

Answer (score 1):

#### Generate New Paper Wallet

Here are the steps to create a new paper wallet that contains your public address and your unencrypted private key (to be kept secret) using https://www.myetherwallet.com/:

1. Go to https://www.myetherwallet.com/.
2. Ensure that "MYETHERWALLET LLC" is displayed next to the green lock icon. This ensures that you are not being attacked via phishing or man-in-the-middle attack.

   [image]
3. Enter a password.
4. Click the *Create New Wallet* button.
5. Click the *Download Keystore File (UTC / JSON)* button.
6. A file with a name of the format `UTC--<date>--<address>` is now saved on your filesystem. An example filename is `UTC--2017-12-05T16-48-22.864Z--dd7d0aff035936edde52e7481aebbc527a3bd944`. Here is an example content of this file.

   ```
   {
     "version": 3,
     "id": "144a3fbb-166a-4812-8994-7fbb67453288",
     "address": "dd7d0aff035936edde52e7481aebbc527a3bd944",
     "Crypto": {
       "ciphertext": "fb0396c0b6629232236bc66ffc87ed2390725902f3cbd9cbece3a67a36b27b0f",
       "cipherparams": {
         "iv": "545695ada7f16fbb5b0c0be4d9c57306"
       },
       "cipher": "aes-128-ctr",
       "kdf": "scrypt",
       "kdfparams": {
         "dklen": 32,
         "salt": "25e69b30c724629e5abcd68486f20e45fb13e58fb088d06dd9f2caeec9b1d6b9",
         "n": 1024,
         "r": 8,
         "p": 1
       },
       "mac": "d299ae9a17717611c89101039a64a39e1b701efface8e2025eb3c6634129cdef"
     }
   }
   ```

   **Caution: Never share this keystore file with anyone!**
7. Now click the *"I understand. Continue."* button
8. The private key is now displayed. You may save this private key. **Caution: Never share this private key with anyone! If you choose to save this, save it securely such that it cannot fall in the wrong hands.**

   [image]
9. Now click either the *Print Paper Wallet* button. This gives you a paper wallet that you can print on paper and save it in a secure physical location.

   [image]

   Alternatively, you can just copy your address and your private key and save it wherever you wish. Note that the private key should be saved in a secure manner such that it does not fall into the hands of the wrong person.

#### What Must Be Saved

Note that you need to have at least one of the following to recover your wallet in future:

- The keystore password entered in step 3 along with the (UTC / JSON) file downloaded in steps 5 and 6.
- The private key (displayed in step 8 or step 9).

The above requirement is clarified further in the following points:

- If you forget the keystore password, you cannot recover your wallet with the keystore file.
- If you do not have the keystore file, you cannot recover your wallet with the keystore password.
- The keystore file must be used with the keystore password to recover your wallet.
- If you only have the private key alone, you can recover your wallet, i.e., if you have the private key, you don't need anything else to recover your wallet. The private key alone is sufficient to recover your wallet.

#### Get Paper Wallet from Keystore (UTC/JSON) File

Here are the steps to recover your wallet detais (public address and private key) or print a paper wallet from your keystore password and the keystore file:

1. Go to https://www.myetherwallet.com/ > [View Wallet Info](https://www.myetherwallet.com/#view-wallet-info) and select *Keystore / JSON File*.
2. Click the *SELECT WALLET FILE...` button, browse to your keystore file and select it.
3. Then enter the keystore password and click *Unlock*.

   [image]
4. Your public address is now displayed. Click on the eye icon next to the private key to view the unencrypted private key.

   [image]
5. Click on *Print Paper Wallet* to print, view, or copy your paper wallet.

#### Get Paper Wallet from Private Key

Here are the steps to retrieve your wallet information from the private key alone.

1. Go to https://www.myetherwallet.com/ > [View Wallet Info](https://www.myetherwallet.com/#view-wallet-info) and select *Private Key*.
2. Enter the private key and click *Unlock*.

   [image]
3. Your public address is now displayed. Click on the eye icon next to the private key to view the unencrypted private key.

   [image]
4. Click on *Print Paper Wallet* to print, view, or copy your paper wallet.