# What would be the steps required to entirely derive an address with pen and paper?

Tags: accounts, security, paper-wallets

I'd like to see the steps required to derive an address by hand, with pen and paper, along with an estimate of time required.

**Is it feasible to derive an address entirely with pen and paper?**

**What are the steps required to derive an account?**

**Approximately (order of magnitude) how long would it take to perform each step?**

Related questions:

[How to generate paper wallet on myetherwallet.com?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/15798/how-to-generate-paper-wallet-on-myetherwallet-com)

[How is an Ether paper wallet created?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/18029/how-is-an-ether-paper-wallet-created)

[Is there a way to generate ethereum paper wallets?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/103/is-there-a-way-to-generate-ethereum-paper-wallets)

[Offline Wallet Generation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/17153/offline-wallet-generation)

Comment: Nice question, I really would like to know the answer but I don't think it belongs to this site. Try Reddit or some forums.

Comment: @NicolasMassart Thanks, I've made it more concise. I'd argue it's on topic and not opinion based...